# How does the series $\sum\frac{x^{n+1}}{n3^{n}}$ converge when $x = -3$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

My lecturer said it converges at $x = -3$ and diverges at $x=3$. I agree it diverges at $x = 3$ because it is the series $\sum\frac{3}{n}$. But at $x = -3$, isn't it $\sum-\frac{3}{n}$ which diverges as well?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: It's $-3\sum (-1)^n/n$

Answer (score 1):

At $x=-3$ we get the series

$$3 \sum \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}.$$

Greetings from Leibniz !

Answer (score 1):

No, the series is
$$\sum_{n\ge1} \dfrac{3(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$
which converges to $3 \log2$. (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series).)

Comment: but how did u simplify it to get that?

Comment: $$\dfrac{(-3)^{n+1}}{n\cdot3^n} = \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(3)^{n+1}}{n\cdot3^n} = \dfrac{(-1)^n3}{n}.$$ (I originally made a typo in my answer.)

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you! sometimes the simplest stuff makes u scratch ur head haha.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! (It may be handy to keep in mind that negatives and exponents don't work as "cleanly" as positives and exponents.)